# Jquery parent() and closest() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, closest

Good morning this is my HTML: tab2 is not static, I can have tabn. 
I want to get the id of the parent of taskFilter tab2, but I am getting the tab-home, this is my js.

```js
var ntab = $('#taskFilter').closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
var ntab2 = $('#taskFilter').parent().attr('id');
vat ntab3 = $('#taskFilter').parent().parent().attr('id');
console.log(ntab, ntab2, ntab3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab-home" class="tab-pane"></div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
    <div id="tasksFilter"></div>
</div>
```

The log result is;

```
ntab = tab-home,   
ntab2 = undefined,   
ntab3 = indefined.
```

Or if you can tell me another way to get de id of taskFilter's parent
Thanks for help.

Comment: You have multiple typos in your selectors. `#taskfilter` should be `#tasksFilter`. Also, you have `vat` instead of `var`. Fix that and your first two examples work fine.

Comment: Please take better care of your code examples. Typos are really unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the typos in your code, the output is:

```
tab2 tab2 undefined
```

The last undefined is because `taskfilter` has no grandparent.

```js
var ntab = $('#taskfilter').closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
var ntab2 = $('#taskfilter').parent().attr('id');
var ntab3 = $('#taskfilter').parent().parent().attr('id');
console.log(ntab, ntab2, ntab3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab-home" class="tab-pane"></div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
  <div id="taskfilter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed the typos, but I am still getting "tab-home"

Comment: Have you tried the code snippet in my answer? It's less than 10 lines... you should be able to find the differences with your code.

Comment: I did it, and I fixed them,I think the problem is beacuse <div id="tab2"> and <div id="taskfilter"> are in different views.

Comment: We can only work with the code we have, if you can reproduce the error in a code snippet it would be easy to look at.

Comment: I can't, it is too much code. I am going to try another way. Thanks

Comment: `parent()` and `closest()` both work by finding an ancestor to the element in the DOM tree.  Regardless of how the tree is built, if parent is coming back undefined, then that would suggest you have a detached element or your selection that you are performing the parent off of was not found.  The same is true for closest, however it can also return undefined if the selector you give for closest does not match against an ancestor.